# audio in android app fails to play

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

For some reason i do not know my audio files fails to play after compiling. I upload my files over to the build over some months ago and after the compilation, the audio was playing. 
Just yesterday i upload the same files again with a little bit of changes but no changes made to the audio script and its failing to playing after the download.

I get this error `code:1 message undefined`

music.js

```
// JavaScript Document



  `enter code here`      // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        //function onDeviceReady() {
           // playAudio(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "Playlist/music/Eminado.mp3");
       // }

       function play2face() {
        playAudio('/android_asset/www/Playlist/music/African Queen.mp3');
        }


        // Audio player
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;
        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio(url) {
            // Create Media object from url
            stopAudio()
            my_media = new Media(url, onSuccess, onError);

            // Play audio
            my_media.play();        

        }

        // Pause audio
        // 
        function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                this.my_media.pause();
            }
        }

        // Stop audio
        // 
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                this.my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;
        }

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback 
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="play2face();">Play Music </a>| <a href="#" onclick="pauseAudio()";>Pause Music</a> | <a onclick="stopAudio();" href="#">Stop Music</a>
```

I've got cordova.js too in the head section of my index.html

also i have these plugins included in the config.xml

```
<plugin name="nl.nilscorver.cordova.media" spec="0.2.18" source="pgb" />
    <plugin name="br.com.paveisitemas.splashscreen" spec="2.1.1" source="pgb" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" spec="0.6.0" source="pgb" />
    <plugin name="com.surfernetwork.fileplugin" spec="1.0.2" source="pgb" />
```

any help on how to make it play?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JS expert so I can't really help you there, but I will add that android has a built-in Music player class that you should use when playing audio. I'm sorry I can't help more :(